# Set an array inside an array of objects using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If we have an array that contains objects that each contain and array of tags like shown below:

```
const arr = [
  {
    0: {
      name: 'Apple',
      tags: ['fruit', 'green']
    }
  },
  {
    1: {
      name: 'ball',
      tags: ['round']
    }
  },
  {
    2: {
      name: 'cat',
      tags: ['grey', 'meow', 'treats']
    }
  }
];
```

Is it possible to use react hooks to update the array of tags? I was trying something like this but got confused:

```
setArr((prev => 
            ([...prev,
            ({...prev[id],
            [...prev[id]['tags'],
            prev[id]['tags']: newArrOftags ]})],
        ));
```

Comment: You need to first identify the index of the object you are trying to update, or use a `map()`

Comment: I have the index identified already. In fact, it works when I use the regular javascript method: arr[id]['tags'] = newArrOfTags; However, it does not re-render immediately so I have to use hooks.

Comment: You may want to rethink your strategy with your object structure, if indeed that is an accurate representation of your structure (use `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2))` to get a better picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the simplest syntax that I would use to target a specific item in your array, given you know the number value used within that item, and then update the previous state within your useState hook:

```
const lookup = 1; // Using the correct number value to target ball
const newItem = 'Additional ball tag here';
  
setArr((prevArr) => {
    const newArr = prevArr.map((item) => {
        if (item[lookup]) {
            item[lookup].tags = [...item[lookup].tags, newItem];
        }

        return item;
    });

    return newArr;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using short hand syntax which is a bit complex in your case, here is what you need. I am looping through the array using map and finding the object with id. Then appending the tags to that object's tags array. In the example I am adding a few tags to an object with id 1.

```
let arr = [
  {
    0: {
      name: 'Apple',
      tags: ['fruit', 'green']
    }
  },
  {
    1: {
      name: 'ball',
      tags: ['round']
    }
  },
  {
    2: {
      name: 'cat',
      tags: ['grey', 'meow', 'treats']
    }
  }
];

const id = 1;
const tags = ["test1","test2","test3"]

arr = arr.map((a)=>{
  
  if(Object.keys(a).includes(id.toString()))
  {
    a[id].tags = [...a[id].tags,...tags];
  }
  return a;
})
```

Use the above logic instead of spread operator to set state. `map` returns a new array so it's safe to use for state updates.

Here is an example of the logic: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xqnjai